# Одно из значений intent не приходит

Tags: android, android-intent

Через метод `startActivityForResult()` из активити B в активити А приходит информация.

Все данные благополучно кладутся в интент - кроме одного интового параметра. Он всегда равен нулю.

Логировал, в активити B при отправке он заполнен правильным значением, при получении (точно таком же - как и другие значения) он всегда равен нулю.

Приложу весь `startActivityForResult()` , если понадобится еще информация, дополню:

Активити получающая данные:

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            @Importance
            int importance = data.getExtras().getInt("Importance"); //эта строка, при этом если мне не изменяет память, я убирал аннотацию, не помогло.

            String header = data.getExtras().getString("header");
            String body = data.getExtras().getString("body");
            String date = data.getExtras().getString("date");
            Log.v("date", "Время = " + date);

            contentValues.put(dbHelper.KEY_HEADER, header);
            contentValues.put(dbHelper.KEY_BODY, body);

            contentValues.put(dbHelper.IMPORTANCE, importance);
            Log.v("imp",""+importance);

            contentValues.put(dbHelper.DATE, date);

            long newItemIndex = database.insert(dbHelper.TABLE_NOTES, null, contentValues);

             fragment.addNewItem(header, body, importance, date, (int) newItemIndex);


            cursor.close();
        }
        dbHelper.close();

    }
```

UPD:

Активити B, получение и запаковка:

```
  spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


                intent = new Intent();
                switch (spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()) {

                    case 0:
                        intent.putExtra("importance", Importance.noMatter);
                        Log.v("итем", "item = 0 " + spinner.getSelectedItemPosition());
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        Log.v("итем", "item = 1 " + spinner.getSelectedItemPosition());
                        intent.putExtra("importance", Importance.green);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        intent.putExtra("importance", Importance.yellow);
                        Log.v("итем", "item = 2 " + 2);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        intent.putExtra("importance", Importance.red);
                        Log.v("итем", "item = 3 " + 3);
                        break;
                    default:
                        intent.putExtra("importance", Importance.noMatter);
                        Log.v("итем", "дефолт = " + spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

        header.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (header.getText().length() == 32) {
                    header.setError("Слишком длинный заголовок");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });


        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (header.getText().length() == 0) {
                    header.setError("Необходимо заполнить");
                    return;
                } else {
                    intent.putExtra("header", header.getText().toString());
                    Log.v("new", "header " + header.getText());

                }
                if (body.getText().length() == 0) {
                    body.setError("Необходимо заполнить");
                    return;
                } else {
                    intent.putExtra("body", body.getText().toString());
                }
                intent.putExtra("date", getDate());

                Log.v("new", "body " + body.getText());
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);

                finish();

            }
        });
```

Comment: А как пакуете данные?

Comment: @post_zeew обновил вопрос.

Comment: А по нажатию `save` в `intent` точно есть значение `Importance`?

Comment: @post_zeew `V/new: importance в момент нажатия на сохранить = 3` лог

Comment: Это именно в методе `onClick` кнопки `save`? Посмотрите через отладчик содержимое сформированного интента.

Comment: @post_zeew `Log.v("new", "importance в момент нажатия на сохранить = " + intent.getExtras().getInt("importance"));`
`
это в обработчике кнопки

Comment: "Importance" <> "importance". Регистр у вас разный. Пользуйтесь константами.

Comment: @YuraIvanov Вы правы, отметьте как ответ, пожалуйста.

Comment: Тоже часто приходится перекидывать данные из активити в активити. Чтоб постоянно не сооружать `putExtra/getExtra` делаю синглтон, класс вешаю на `Application`. В некоторых случаях весьма удобно)

Comment: Эпично получилось. А еще лучше в получающих активити делать статические методы, которые будут получать данные, запаковывать их и возвращать сам интент.

Comment: @post_zeew я постоянно на невнимательности по полдня сижу)

Comment: @Pollux, А вот так лучше не делать. Синглтон – это не панацея от всех проблем, и в случаях, где можно обойтись без него – нужно обходиться без него.

Comment: @post_zeew, так вроде же это простой класс, как в данном случае, хранения данных, нагрузки не создает. Подскажите, почему лучше без него? Может я какой-то его особенности не знаю..

Comment: @Pollux, http://savepic.ru/11973287.jpg

Comment: @post_zeew, спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Importance" <> "importance". Регистр у вас разный. Пользуйтесь константами:

```
public static final String IMPORTANCE = "importance";
...
intent.putExtra(IMPORTANCE, Importance.noMatter);
...
@Importance
int importance = data.getExtras().getInt(ActivityB.IMPORTANCE);
```

Константы можно вынести в отдельный класс, если они используются и в других местах.